# DynamoDB - Item Not Uploading

Tags: objective-c, ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to `DynamoDB` and I want to use it to store key strings that I will match with S3 objects. Here is my code to upload a string:

```
AmazonCredentials *amazonCreds = [[AmazonCredentials alloc] initWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY_ID withSecretKey: SECRET_KEY];

AmazonDynamoDBClient *dClient = [[AmazonDynamoDBClient alloc] initWithCredentials: amazonCreds];

[dClient setEndpoint: [AmazonEndpoints s3Endpoint:AP_SOUTHEAST_1 secure: YES]];

NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [[DynamoDBAttributeValue alloc] initWithS: req.key],
                          @"QuoteKey",
                          nil];

DynamoDBPutItemRequest *dReq = [[DynamoDBPutItemRequest alloc] initWithTableName:@"TestQuotesTable" andItem: [dict mutableCopy]];
DynamoDBPutItemResponse *dRes = [dClient putItem: dReq];
```

But when I go to the console and enter the table, the item is not uploaded.... is there something wrong with my code. When I first created my table in `DynamoDB` the default key/attribute name is "QuoteKey" so everything should be fine.

Anything wrong with my code? Thanks

Comment: Might be a problem with authentication. Can you do other types of requests?

Comment: @Guy No I cannot, I suspect that it is because i am not using TVM... im gonna try that out and get back to you

Comment: @RohanKapur hello mate ..plz help regarding DynamoDB . i dont know about this topic .plz help ..thanks in Advance

Comment: @Bajaj Bajaj, create a new StackOverflow question with your doubts and Ill help you out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the endpoint for your client to an S3 endpoint, not DynamoDB.  You'll want to replace:

```
[dClient setEndpoint: [AmazonEndpoints s3Endpoint:AP_SOUTHEAST_1 secure: YES]];
```

With the following:

```
[dClient setEndpoint: [AmazonEndpoints ddbEndpoint:AP_SOUTHEAST_1 secure: YES]];
```

Comment: THat is problem with the code when I was pasting it into Stack Overflow. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @Bob hello mate ..plz help regarding DynamoDB . i dont know about this topic .plz help ..thanks in Advance

Comment: @Bajaj As Rohan already pointed out, you'll want to create a new question in order to get some assistance.